# How to push object to forms in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to push the roles form data value to createUserForm data value so that they will become  1 object ?

#The final result should look like this

```
{
    "emailAddress": "asdasdas@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "sdsfd",
    "lastName": "fsdfsdf",
    "phoneNumber": "21324",
    "companyName": "sdfsdf",
    "title": "CEO",
    "roleId": 7,
    "associatedAccount": "WALLS",
    "accountId": 4,
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Architect",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 12
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Construction Project Director",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 11
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "COVP",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the data from roles when I submit

```
 {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Architect",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 12
    }
```

This is the data from createUserForm when I submit

```
{
    "emailAddress": "adasd",
    "firstName": "asdasdasd",
    "lastName": "asdasd",
    "phoneNumber": "2132",
    "companyName": "adasdas",
    "title": "dasdasdas",
    "roleId": 7,
    "associatedAccount": "test",
    "accountId": 4
}
```

--->>> another form

```
roles = new FormControl();
```

--->>>> User Form

```
 createUserForm = new FormGroup({
    emailAddress: new FormControl(),
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    lastName: new FormControl(),
    phoneNumber:  new FormControl(),
    companyName: new FormControl(),
    title: new FormControl(),
    roleId: new FormControl(),
    associatedAccount: new FormControl(),
    accountId: new FormControl(),
  });
```

--->>> what i tried

```
 saveUser() {
        this.createUserForm.get('roleId').setValue(7);
        console.log("this.createUserForm.value" , this.createUserForm.value)
        console.log("data" ,this.roles.value)
        console.log("finaldata : " ,
 this.createUserForm.value.push(this.roles.value))
```

Comment: Ideally you should create a new field `roles` as a `formArray` inside the `createUserForm` this will do what you need out of the box, but somehow you have both separate and `this.roles.value` has the value which you need and only want to merge it with `this.createUserForm.value` then you can simply use this approach `const formValues = { ...this.createUserForm.value, roles: this.roles.value } `

Comment: and Kamran , how to I store each formValues to an array of objects? cause in my program I wanted to store every formValues to an array of objects or push it

Comment: For that you have to go with the approach I suggested above, lemme create a stackblitz example of form which will address your case give me a moment.

Comment: Okay , like I wanna create a allFormValues array of object then push every const formValues to it

Comment: you can either use the angular formbuilder by injecting it into your constructor and then using this._formbuilder.build({}). It sets up the formControls by itself and you can feed infos and validators directly like this._formBuilder.build({emailAddress: ['myEmail@address, [Validators.Email]], ... }). Or you can patch your form value by accessing single elements via this.createUserForm.get('emailAddress').patchValue();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [angular reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) try this out.

```
 import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

 form: FormGroup;

 constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

 this.form = this._fb.group({
  firstName: [],
  emailAddress: [],
  ...
  roles: this._fb.array([]) // create a role form field as an array
});
```

You can call a method to add role object to form array

```
addRole(): void {
  const roles = this.form.get('roles') as FormArray;

  roles.push(
     this._fb.group({ id: [], name: [], isShow: [], transactionRoleId: [] 
    })
  );

  console.log(this.form.value);
}
```

Or can remove the added role by its index

```
removeRole(index: number): void {
  const roles = this.form.get('roles') as FormArray;

  roles.removeAt(index);
}
```